# ADFv2 Lookup Activity timeout after 2 hours even after increasing query timeout value

Tags: azure-sql-database, lookup, azure-data-factory, query-timeout

I have a lookup activity that timeouts after the 2 hours (120 mins) which is the default (could be just a coincidence) even after increasing the query timeout to 720 mins.
The lookup activity executes a Proc based on an expression.

[image]

This is the error

> Failure happened on 'Source' side.
> ErrorCode=UserErrorSourceQueryTimeout,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Query
> source database timeout after '7200'
> seconds.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''Type=System.TimeoutException,Message=,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,'

[image]

[image]

Is there a step that I've missed out somewhere?

Comment: I mean two hours is a long long time in stored proc terms.  Consider resolving that performance issue first, with indexing, tuning etc.  Consider splitting it up into two steps where a Stored Proc activity executes the proc, or maybe precompile that data overnight?  And then the Lookup is only looking up data in a table.

Comment: the ADF pipeline that the Lookup activity belongs to forms part of an overnight DWH ETL process, 
This particular SP runs long only occoassionaly.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two timeouts in Lookup activity, one is `Lookup activity timeout` and other is `queryTimeout`. Please make sure that to set the `queryTimeout` value lower than the `lookup activity timeout` value. `queryTimeout` won't be effective if it is greater than lookup activity timeout (24hrs).

**Note:** When you use query or stored procedure to lookup data, make sure to return one and exact one result set. Otherwise, Lookup activity fails.

Refer: [Lookup activity in Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#supported-capabilities)

Comment: the `queryTimeout` value (720mins) is lower than the `lookup activity timeout` value (7 days default) so this doesn't help